# ¿Qué significa el &&? y ¿Cómo lo interpreto?

Tags: c++, bucle-for, dev-c++

```
if(i>0&&i>99&&i<999){ 
        cout<<"El número ingresado es correcto"<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"El número ingresado esta fuera de rango"<<endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Las tres condiciones tienen que cumplirse, que `i` sea mayor a cero, `i` sea mayor a *99* e `i` sea menor a *999*.

En el siguiente ejemplo se puede ver cómo se engaña a la vista haciendo creer que no se cumple la primera condición:

```
char i = 'o';
if(i>0&&i>99&&i<999){
    cout<< i <<" es correcto"<<endl;
}
else {
    cout<< i <<" esta fuera de rango"<<endl;
}
```

Resultado:

```
o es correcto
```

Esto es porque `i` es `o`, que es la [decimosexta letra del abecedario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/O) en minúscula, que en decimal es *111*, esto hace que se cumpla la primera condición y las otras dos.

Otro ejemplo, casteando un `int` como `short`, se declara `i` con el valor *66000*, que no cumple ninguna de las tres condiciones:

```
short i = (short)66000;
if(i>0&&i>99&&i<999){
    cout << "Es correcto."<< endl;
} else {
    cout << "Esta fuera de rango." << endl;
}
```

Salida del programa:

```
Es correcto.
```

El tipo de dato `short` soporta números *desde -32767 hasta 32767*. Al castearlo a `short`, en caso de superar el máximo le resta *65536*. Entonces *66000 restado 65536 da 464*, lo cual hace que se cumplan todas las condiciones.